# How to use gvim color scheme with vimdiff output

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I am running gvim -d in a batch file and generating HTML output using TOhtml. I would like to use the console version of vimdiff to get a slight performance increase but it insists on using the 256 bit console color scheme.
Is there any way to tell the console vimdiff to use a gui color scheme when it builds HTML output using TOhtml?

Comment: Hi! I'm actually the listed maintainer of the standard TOhtml plugin, and I've already had a feature request to add the ability to use the GUI colors when running in console mode. I'll post back here when I actually get around to it; I've not done much work on the plugin recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:TOhtml` command uses the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/2html.vim` script to convert the buffer's colors into HTML. That one uses a `has("gui_running")` condition for the GUI colors, and else falls back to hard-coded terminal colors. So even with recent patches to support 24-bit colors in (certain) terminals, you won't get the GUI colors without an extension to the `2html` script. So far, you have to use GVIM to get them.